# Bash receive stderr from a pipe which did not redirect it

Tags: bash, stderr

Is it possible to receive/redirect the stderr of `foo.sh` from within `bar.sh` if called without redirecting it first: `foo.sh | bar.sh`?

**foo.sh**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world" >&2
```

**bar.sh**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sed -Eu 's/world/everyone/g'
```

```bsh
user@pc$ ./foo.sh | ./bar.sh
hello world

user@pc$ ./foo.sh 2>&1 | ./bar.sh
hello everyone
```

Is it possible to make `bar.sh` behave like the second example even if the user accidentally calls it like in the first example?

BTW, `foo.sh` can be any process that writes to `stderr`. I'm just interested in how to receive it from `bar.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the idea is to filter out data on stderr, there's a better way to do that, without merging the streams or losing all of stderr: `my_command 2> >(grep --invert-match secret_regex >&2)`

Syntax explanation:

- `2>` says "send standard error to the next word in the command"
- `>(some_command)` says to send the thing before it to standard *input* of the command.
- `>&2` at the end sends the `grep` output (the lines *not* matching a secret) *back to standard error.*

Example, showing how stdout and stderr are intact after filtering:

```
$ (echo output; echo error >&2; echo secret >&2) 2> >(grep --invert-match secret >&2)
output
error
$ ((echo output; echo error >&2; echo secret >&2) 2> >(grep --invert-match secret >&2)) 2>/dev/null
output
$ ((echo output; echo error >&2; echo secret >&2) 2> >(grep --invert-match secret >&2)) >/dev/null
error
```

---

Original answer: When you call `./foo.sh | ./bar.sh`, standard error of `foo.sh` ends up wherever it was set to by the shell (that is, before the two commands ran). I don't believe it's possible (without root access) for `bar.sh` to "hijack" where standard error is pointing, as that would be a big security hole: a rogue process could hijack the output of some command which is printing sensitive information.

Comment: Would it be possible to know if the user did not pass `stderr` and then clear the screen or do something that blocks the output? The point of `bar.sh` is to filter out sensitive data, but if the sensitive data is in `stder`, (and it was not piped), then the sensitive data still shows up on screen.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` offers a shorthand:

> If **|&** is used, command's standard error, in addition to its standard
> output,  is  connected  to command2's  standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for **2>&1 |**